# set top 20% value to 1 of each row and bottom 20% value to -1 and np.nan the other

Tags: python, pandas

suppose I have a dataframe like this

```
    0  1  2  3  4    5    6    7    8     9
0   1  2  3  4  5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1   1  2  3  4  5  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0
2  10  9  8  7  6  5.0  4.0  3.0  2.0   1.0
```

I want to set top 20% value to 1 of each row and bottom 20% value to -1 and np.nan the other.(ignore the nan value)

```
   0    1   2   3    4   5   6   7    8    9
0 -1  NaN NaN NaN  1.0 NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
1 -1 -1.0 NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0
2  1  1.0 NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN -1.0 -1.0
```

now I realize it using for loop but it is really slow when the number of row is large. Is there any faster way to realize it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
#DataFrame to numpy array
a = df.to_numpy()
#count number of non missing values and then 20%
s = df.count(axis=1).mul(0.2).astype(int).to_numpy()

#get indices for top and bottom 20%
m1 = np.argsort(a) < s[:, None]
m2 = np.argsort((np.argsort(-a))) < s[:, None]

#set values by conditions
df = pd.DataFrame(np.select([m1, m2], [-1, 1], np.nan))
print (df)
     0    1   2   3    4   5   6   7    8    9
0 -1.0  NaN NaN NaN  1.0 NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
1 -1.0 -1.0 NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0 NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN -1.0 -1.0
```

Test:

```
a=np.array([[1., np.nan, 2.], [1.,2.,np.nan], [np.nan, 2.,1.]])
print (a)
[[ 1. nan  2.]
 [ 1.  2. nan]
 [nan  2.  1.]]

print(np.argsort(a))
[[0 2 1]
 [0 1 2]
 [2 1 0]]

print(np.argsort((np.argsort(-a))))
[[1 2 0]
 [1 0 2]
 [2 0 1]]
```

Comment: I think argsort can't deal with nan value. For exsample, `a=np.array([1, np.nan, 2])`. `np.argsort(a) < 1` is `array([ True, False, False])` and `np.argsort(-a) < 1` is `array([False,  True, False])`

Comment: may I ask your numpy version?

Comment: @xxyao - `numpy            : 1.20.1`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use numpy **nanpercentile**

your example data is :

```
import pandas as pd
data = np.array([
[1,  2 , 3,  4,  5,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,   np.nan],
[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6.0,  7.0,  8.0,  9.0,  10.0],
[  10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5.0,  4.0,  3.0,  2.0,   1.0]] )
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

my helper function :

```
import numpy as np

def max_min(arr: np.array) -> np.array:
    low_perc = np.nanpercentile(arr,20)
    high_perc = np.nanpercentile(arr,80)    
    return -(arr<low_perc).astype(int) + (arr>high_perc).astype(int)
```

and the way to use it :

```
df.apply(max_min,axis=1)
```

that gives :

```
     0    1   2   3    4   5   6   7    8    9
0 -1.0  NaN NaN NaN  1.0 NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
1 -1.0 -1.0 NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0 NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN -1.0 -1.0
```